# How to secure my web widget embedded from third party website

Tags: javascript, wordpress, security, plugins, widget

I am creating web widget that can embed in other websites. Here is an example.

```
<script src="http://URL/searchWidget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<search-view name="search"></search-view>
```

I have some specific clients and only I am providing those widgets to those clients. So I need to secure those widgets from other third party websites. My Clients are using CMS, Joomla, Drupal.

If I give a widget(above script tag) to the client, only that client has access to that widget. If someone stolen that script, they cannot access that widget.

How can I do that ? 
Is there any secure way to build widgets ? 
can I do that using CMS plugin ?

Comment: you need ti check domain name from javascript file. Thats its valid domain or not.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: or you need give unique id for your client

Comment: How can I access that ID. Passing through script tag is not right

Comment: You can access that ID and pass in ajax call verify the domain. if ID is not valid mean do not show your widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this script in your javacsript to get current domain.

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
SiteHostUrl = scripts[scripts.length-1].src;
jsUrl = SiteHostUrl;
```

Or you need give unique id for your client. You can access that ID and pass in ajax call verify the domain. if ID is not valid mean do not show your widget

Comment: "if ID is not valid mean do not show your widget". Do you know how to stop showing the widget when ID is not valid

Comment: Need to check your code. something like  return false or some other way. It is based on code.

Comment: using style.display I can hide the elements and this answer is correct. But the thing is what if we have API requests. They can access through the network tab in the browser. Do you know a solution for that.

Comment: it is based on code. Need to check your code. add condition if valid mean process your script else show invalid something. I'm using this kind code in my widget script. But I'm not using hide. I will stop the next step the code if it is not valid code.